# Feature class to feature class code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase

I have some code that will take a ArcGIS 10.2.2 feature class and post a copy of it in a different geodatabase.

My code is set up so the end user can pick the feature class they want the model to run (getparameterastext).  My problem is the code doesn't name the new feature class the same name as the original feature class.  My code "hard codes" a name to the new feature class being posted.  What do I need to change the my code so the new file will name the new feature class the same name of the original feature class the end user pics?  This is what my code looks like.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
maint_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sdr_staging_gdb = "Y:\\data\\dev\\staging\\sdr_staging.gdb"
staging = "Y:\\data\\dev\\staging"

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(maint_FC, sdr_staging_gdb, 'maint_FC', "", "POL_DIST \"POL_DIST\" true true false 3 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,POL_DIST,-1,-1;INSPECTOR \"INSPECTOR\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,INSPECTOR,-1,-1;INSP_NBR \"INSP_NBR\" true true false 3 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,INSP_NBR,-1,-1;COMMENT \"COMMENT\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,COMMENT,-1,-1;DATE_MOD \"DATE_MOD\" true true false 36 Date 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,DATE_MOD,-1,-1;DATE_ADDED \"DATE_ADDED\" true true false 36 Date 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,DATE_ADDED,-1,-1;MOD_BY \"MOD_BY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,MOD_BY,-1,-1;ADDED_BY \"ADDED_BY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,ADDED_BY,-1,-1;Shape_STArea__ \"Shape_STArea__\" false false true 0 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,Shape.STArea(),-1,-1;Shape_STLength__ \"Shape_STLength__\" false false true 0 Double 0 0 ,First,#,Database Connections\\UGGSSSQL_GISPUB_basemap.sde\\gispub.BASEMAP.gisdata\\gispub.BASEMAP.TL_TEST_2,Shape.STLength(),-1,-1", "")

# Process: Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(maint_FC, staging)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Describe function to grab the name or basename](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/018v00000013000000/) of the feature class, and use it for the output name.

```
import arcpy

maint_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

workspace_type = str(arcpy.Describe(arcpy.Describe(maint_FC).path).workspaceFactoryProgID)

if workspace_type == "esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory.1":
    maint_FC_name = str(arcpy.Describe(maint_FC).baseName).split(".")[-1]
else:
    maint_FC_name = str(arcpy.Describe(maint_FC).baseName)

sdr_staging_gdb = "Y:\\data\\dev\\staging\\sdr_staging.gdb"

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(maint_FC, sdr_staging_gdb, maint_FC_name, "#", "#")
```

Comment: The code works fine. It just names the new feature class "maint_FC".  I want the code to call the feature class the same name as the one picked by the end user.

Comment: @Nebula93 well that's what this should do, good luck.

Comment: That didn't work....It just named the file "maint_FC_name"....thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Nebula93 then you must have put quotes around "maint_FC_name". It should be exactly how I have it in my example. There shouldn't be any quotes, it should just say maint_FC_name because it's a variable.

Comment: Copy/pasted your code got this error.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tlathrop\Desktop\GeoDatabase\Scripts\staging_5.py", line 8,in<module>arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(maint_FC, sdr_staging_gdb, maint_FC_name, "#", "#")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1675, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise eExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Y:\data\dev\staging\sdr_staging.gdb\GISMAINT.GIS_OWNER.April_Test1ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass

Comment: @Nebula93 it looks like you're copying data from SDE to a file geodatabase. In SDE the feature class is named GISMAINT.GIS_OWNER.April_Test1 which is not a valid name. I assume you just want April_Test1 as the output name? I've edited the code in my answer.